# Understanding the ice-water phase transition in order to apply it on solid-solid phase transitions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, simulations, phase-transition, nucleation

## Background

I'm trying to understand a solid-solid phase transition. In this transition, a crystalline material changes from one phase to the other. An example would be the alpha iron / gamma iron transition. In this transition the cell structure changes from BCC to FCC. I'm trying to understand it in terms of nucleation theory.

## Water/Ice phase transition

The water/ice phase transition is a first order phase transition. These transitions are characterized by a latent heat. Now my question is what happens when I have 100% water and start to cool it down. Let's assume that at some point an ice cube appears. Since it apparently releases energy to create these cubes, and I'm not removing any more energy, I expect there to be cluster(s) of ice cubes which are stable.

Now, let's cool it down completely until everything is ice. Now I start to heat it up again. Does the phase transition occur in the same way, or do I see a hysteresis effect? I expect a hysteresis, because if all but one unit of the water is ice, it will cost less energy (intuitively) to turn that water into ice. However, in order to turn a piece of ice into water, I expect that more energy is needed. This would imply a non-reversible process.

A final question is how to create a model of this phase transition. I have several problems trying to model this in a statistical physics fashion. Since a "neighbour interaction" is included, an Ising-like model would be used. However, this model has a second order phase transition and will have slightly below Tc states where nearly all states are either liquid or ice, where very small nuclei can be created by thermal activation. This doesn't seem like a nice model here. A fix would be to limit the amount of energy available, so there's only a fixed amount of energy in order to create/destroy ice/water. Modeling this would not generate stable states, though, as due to thermal means states can locally change.

Questions:

1) Is my cluster assumption correct? Would it be possible that locally stable clusters of ice/water form, slowly growing larger until they connect? Or is it just a large cluster? What about solid/solid transitions?

2) Is my assumption of "hysteresis" and "irreversible" processes correct? (How about solid/solid transitions?)

3) How would one model this process?

A pointer to a good source on this would already be a huge help!

Comment: Phase transitions are completely reversible thermodynamically. The latent heat is the latent heat going in either direction. Nucleation and growth are kinetics, not thermodynamics. There is not reason that the kinetics of melting should be the same as the kinetics of solidification, and usually they are not.

Comment: "*if all but one unit of the water is ice, it will cost less energy (intuitively) to turn that water into ice.*" This is not the case. Can you get a hold of Porter and Easterling's *Phase Transformations in Metals and Alloys*? It would likely answer most or all of your questions.

Comment: @Chemomechanics This appears to be the resource I have been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The Ising model has both second and first order phase transitions. The second order one is the famous order/disorder transition that you observe when you change the temperature through the critical temperature at zero external field. The first order transition is between the two ordered states below the critical temperature when you change the sign of the external field. It has all the characteristics of any first order transition (hysteresis, metastability, nucleation and growth, etc.).